# How to declare a dependency between 2 non-custom Gradle tasks

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a Gradle build in which I am publishing the output to the Maven local repo (its used by other modules of a larger non Gradle build).  But doing so generates this warning:

> Gradle detected a problem with the following location:
> 'display\build\outputs\apk\release\display-release.apk'. Reason: Task
> ':display:publishMavenAndroidPublicationToMavenLocal' uses this output
> of task ':display:packageRelease' without declaring an explicit or
> implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being
> produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer
> to
> https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency
> for more details about this problem.

The link suggests that I declare a dependency between the 2 tasks.

But neither of the tasks are custom tasks, they are part of the included plugins. And I despite spending hours trying all kinds of syntax I can't work out how to declare the dependency from the publishToMavenLocal to the package task.

How do I declare it?

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'maven-publish' // So that we can publish the APKs 
}

android {
  ...
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenAndroid(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'com.mygroup.foo'
            artifactId = project.name
            version = 1.2.3'
            artifact "$buildDir/outputs/apk/release/${project.name}-release.apk"

            // Explicitly not generating a pom dependencies node
            // 1) we don't need it because the APK includes all its deps.
on Artifactory.
        }
    }
}

build.finalizedBy publishToMavenLocal
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem stems from this line:

```
artifact "$buildDir/outputs/apk/release/${project.name}-release.apk"
```

The APK at that location is created by *some* task. Instead of referencing that tasks' **output**, you have given a direct path. Because of that, Gradle is not able to accurately deduce task dependencies.

I am not an Android developer, but judging from the error:

> uses this output of task ':display:packageRelease' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency.

The project `display` has a task named `packageRelease` which may or may not come from the Android Gradle plugin. Again, I am not an Android developer, so do not know for certain. The `packageRelease` is what produces the APK at the aforementioned path.

The `publishMavenAndroidPublicationToMavenLocal` is created when you create a publication named `mavenAndroid`; this is documented in the [`maven-publish` documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:tasks)

With that said, you must declare task dependencies between the two. Something like:

```
tasks.withType(PublishToMavenRepository::class).configureEach {
    inputFile.from(packageRelease)
}

tasks.withType(PublishToMavenLocal::class).configureEach {
    inputFile.from(packageRelease)
}
```

Without knowing the task type of `packageRelease` and unfamiliarity with Android projects, best I can do above.

Comment: adding either (or both) of those lines generates the following error:
'> Could not find method withType() for arguments [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure@b7a9cb9] on task set of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.'